# spring.net validation

Tags: .net, validation, spring.net

I'm trying to use the Spring.net framework for the first time. I would like to use its validation capabilities.
I'm currently trying to validate business objects, so I have defined several validators (in the App config file).
I retrieve these validators through the IOC (ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject(validator name)).
I would like to know if it's possible to associate a validator to an object as it's the case in the Enterprise library.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

```
IValidator validator = ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("validator name") as IValidator;
IValidationErrors validationErrors = new ValidationErrors();
validator.Validate(myObjectToValidate, validationErrors);
```

you can also use the Validation Aspect (using attributes)